# Delete file from folder and mysql joined table

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

I have a file upload system where I can delete from MySQL DB and from the folder.
The only problem is that all the files in the folder are deleted instead of just the single one. Each folder is a custom folder with a person's name.

I have a joined table where the id's of two tables are equal. I need the joined tabled to receive the name of the person to know the file location.

This is my working code so far where multiple files are deleted instead of the one I selected:

```
$analyse = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT *
                                FROM analyse
                                INNER JOIN persons ON 
                                analyse.id_person = persons.id");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($analyse)) {
    $img = $row['img_name'];
    $name= $row['name'];
    $frontname= $row['frontname'];
    $image_url = "../persons/{$name} {$frontname}/analyse/{$img}";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, "DELETE FROM analyse WHERE id=$id");
    unlink($image_url);
    if($result){
        header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    } else {
        echo "Failed to delete";
    }
}
```

For example: Person X with id 15 has three images with different ids but each time with the ID(15) of the person. I want to be able to delete the single selected file instead of all the files with id 15.

**UPDATE**
I found the solution, the ID that came through for deleting was always the first in my DB row. The fetching of my array was wrong and my ID consequently too.
Thanks for the answers.

Comment: how you pass the id of the selected image?

Comment: I get the ID from the url: 
       $id = $_GET['id'];

Comment: And this how I pass it within my form:


<form> 
                                      <a href="config/deleteImage.php?id=<?php echo $gang['id']; ?>" onClick="return confirm('Ben je zeker dat je <?php echo "".$gang['id']." ".$gang['id'].""?>  wilt verwijderen?')">Verwijder</a>
                                    </form>

Comment: don't write code in comments please update your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using Limit 1 with your delete Query.

```
$analyse = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT *
                                FROM analyse
                                INNER JOIN persons ON analyse.id_person = persons.id");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($analyse)) {
    $img = $row['img_name'];
    $name= $row['name'];
    $frontname= $row['frontname'];
    $image_url = "../persons/{$name} {$frontname}/analyse/{$img}";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, "DELETE FROM analyse WHERE id=$id LIMIT 1");
    unlink($image_url);
    if($result){
        header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    } else {
        echo "Failed to delete";
    }
}
```

Comment: and what if he want's to delete second file instead of first one